# How can I compare the values of different columns for each row?

Tags: r, if-statement, compare

So say I have a dataframe with a column for "play" and two columns with values:

```
df <- data.frame(Play = c("Comedy", "Midsummer", "Hamlet"),
                he = c(105, 20, 210),
                she = c(100, 23, 212))
```

I would like to get two vectors, one containing each Play with a higher value for "he" than "she", and one for the opposite, so each Play that has a higher value for "she" than "he".

I've looked at a few ways I thought going about it but none really seems to work, I tried building a 'if (x > y) {print z}' function then apply() that over my dataframe but I'm really far to inexperienced and run into so many problems, there ought to be simpler way than that …

Comment: Welcome!
What programming language are you using?
Add it to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
as.character(df$Play)[df$he>df$she] 
as.character(df$Play)[df$he<df$she]
```

Are the above 2 expressions solve your problem?